# How to get value from java script reply button into database?

Tags: javascript, php

Below is the Java Script code to display a text box on clicking a Reply button.

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $results )) { 
    echo  "<div class='cmt'>
   <div class='cmttext'></div>
   <button class='replybtn'>Reply</button>
   <div class='replyform'></div>
   </div> ";        
   }
```

and java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var varHtml = "<form method='post' action=''><textarea name='reply'></textarea>  <input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick='history.go(0)' />  <input type='submit' /> </form>";
var allElements = document.body.getElementsByClassName("replybtn");
var addCommentField = function() {
  for (var i = 0; allElements.length > i; i++) {
    if (allElements[i] === this) {
      console.log("this " + i);
      if (document.getElementsByClassName("replyform")[i].innerHTML.length === 0) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("replyform")[i].innerHTML = varHtml;
      }
    }
  }
};

for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
  allElements[i].addEventListener('click', addCommentField, false);
}    
</script>
```

How can I get the values from text box and store it into database?

Comment: Would you like to use AJAX or you just want to submit the form?

Comment: You have to use ajax

Comment: OSDM I wanted the "value" of the text area to be stored into database after the form is submitted. Whatever the way is, either using AJAX or anything else, I wanted the work done. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use Ajax, you'll need to attach a click handler to the button, which will grab the relevant values and send them to a server-side script (e.g. PHP) which can then insert them into the db.

(If you don't want to use Ajax, just use a form and submit it like normal).

Here's a generic example (using jQuery) which does that. You can adapt it to your needs:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ajax example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" id="myTextField" />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function submitValuesToDatabase(values){
        $.ajax({
          url: '/path/to/submit.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: values
        })
        .done(function(res) {
          console.log("success");
          console.log("The server replied: " + res);
        })
        .fail(function(err) {
          console.log("Something went wrong!");
          console.log(err);
        })
        .always(function() {
          console.log("complete");
        });
      }

      $("button").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var values = {
          val1: $("#myTextField").val()
        }
        submitValuesToDatabase(values);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**submit.php**

```
<?php
// Retrieve values from $_POST
// And insert them into database

print_r($_POST);
```

If you run this demo (on a server), you will see output resembling the following in the console:

```
success
The server replied: Array
(
    [val1] => rtzr
)

complete
```

So, in this case to get a reference to val1 in the PHP script you would do:

```
$val1 = filter_var($_POST['val1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Let me know if that's unclear.

Edit: The `.always()` `.fail()` and `.done()` callbacks are not stricly necessary. I included them for demonstration purposes, but feel free to leave them out.

Comment: Thanx for the reply Jack. But I'm new to coding and I don't get it. This is totally a different code, I just wanted to make few changes to my code(code that I have posted) so I can get the value of  <textarea name='reply'></textarea> from the form with variable varHtml(java script) and store it in a php variable. I trying to add a reply button to each comment, for that I have to loop(while) through and have unique ID for each iteration.  Thank you :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this: "get the value of `<textarea name='reply'></textarea>` from the form with variable `varHtml(java script)` and store it in a php variable". Could you elaborate?

Comment: Please have a look at my Java Script, My "form" has been stored in a variable "varHtml". The "form" has a "text area" i.e. <textarea name='reply'></textarea>, that is where the comments are typed into, I wanted to store that comments in a database, How do I do that??